# IIS: The loghttp module in the worker process with id 'm' removed custom log data for 'n' request(s) which was not claimed by the W3C Logging Service

Tags: ssl, iis-10

Please note, this is a copy/cross-post from [forums.iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/post/2145730.aspx).

On various IIS 10.0 web servers (build 14393 and 17763), we have enabled customFields for "[to help identify weak TLS usage](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2017/09/07/new-iis-functionality-to-help-identify-weak-tls-usage/)"

For a couple of servers, this works and new logfiles are create, on the majority it doesn't work: logfiles with customfields are not created and the eventlog shows ID 2309:

> The loghttp module in the worker process with id '9784' removed custom log data for '3' request(s) which was not claimed by the W3C Logging Service.

But as soon as I transfer a website not logging customfields (using msdeploy), to a different web server the customfield logs are created. And other websites on that last server may or may not be logging the customfields...

I created the configuration using PowerShell:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "." -value @{logFieldName='crypt-protocol';sourceName='CRYPT_PROTOCOL';sourceType='ServerVariable'}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "." -value @{logFieldName='crypt-cipher';sourceName='CRYPT_CIPHER_ALG_ID';sourceType='ServerVariable'}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "." -value @{logFieldName='crypt-hash';sourceName='CRYPT_HASH_ALG_ID';sourceType='ServerVariable'}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "." -value @{logFieldName='crypt-keyexchange';sourceName='CRYPT_KEYEXCHANGE_ALG_ID';sourceType='ServerVariable'}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks for saving me time by posting the PowerShell command-lines to set these values! Note that they worked well for me on Windows 10 1809 build 17763.437.

Comment: any update? I also meet this issue recently.

Comment: No update from my side. We dropped the wish to log this type of information in our HTTP log files.